# pycharm opening ports

Tags: ports, network-scanners

By running a simple port scan, I have noticed that pycharm is opening three ports on the machines it is installed on.

Pycharm is a great tool for developer, but it seems fairly awful to me on the security side. Opening ports is a known security hole, and they do not advertise loudly they are doing so.

How can I prevent pycharm from opening ports?

Comment: There may be settings within PyCharm to disable whatever services are listening on ports. It would be a good idea to check the documentation/support site for this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because clearly the author does not know how an application needs to use ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All programs can open ports. Running a firewall would prevent inbound traffic.

Running `netstat -rn` on Linux or OS X will show you all open ports. The ones listening on 127.0.0.1 are not open except to other local programs.

Comment: Thanks for that. Why does running a local scan on 127.0.0.1 show a different result than using the proper IP? The loopback does not send packets to the NIC?

Comment: Loop back “listens” to local traffic. 0.0.0.0 and 10.x.x.x, or whatever your ip is, listens to requests from the local system and from outside.